# Spring Security behavior is different between XML and Java configs

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4.2.4 with a JSF application.

I have the following facelet as the login page.

```
<h:form id="formLogin" prependId="false">
  <center>
    <p:messages closable="true"/>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
      <f:facet name="header">Login</f:facet>

      <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
      <p:inputText id="username" required="true" />

      <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
      <p:password id="password" required="true" feedback="false" />

      <f:facet name="footer">
        <center>
          <p:commandButton value="Login" ajax="false" action="#{loginController.doLogin('login')}"/>
        </center>
      </f:facet>

   </p:panelGrid>
 </center>
</h:form>
```

Where the `doLogin` method in the `LoginController` bean is defined this way:

```
public String doLogin(String path) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    ServletRequest servletRequest = (ServletRequest)context.getRequest();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletRequest.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path.startsWith("/") ? path : "/" + path);
    dispatcher.forward(servletRequest, (ServletResponse)context.getResponse());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

    return null;
}
```

If a define the security configuration using XML this way:

```
<http pattern="/resources/css/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/resources/images/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none"/>

<http>
  <intercept-url pattern="/views/login.xhtml" access="isAnonymous()"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
  <form-login
    login-page="/views/login.xhtml"
    login-processing-url="/login"
    always-use-default-target="true"
    default-target-url="/views/persones.xhtml"/>
  <http-basic/>
  <csrf disabled="true"/>
  <logout invalidate-session="true"
    delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE"
    logout-success-url="/views/login.xhtml">
  </logout>
</http>
```

things go normally and the login proceeds with no problem when I press the login button.

But if I define the security configuration using Java:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/resources/css/**, /resources/images/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/views/login*").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/views/error.xhtml").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/views/login.xhtml")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/views/persones.xhtml", true)
        .and()
          .httpBasic()
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/views/login.xhtml")
          .invalidateHttpSession(true)
          .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE")
        .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

after pressing the login button I end with a 404 error: `myAppContext/login` the requested resource is not found.

Comment: I spent some time fiddling with this today, and I don't see anything wrong with your approach. FWIW, here is a working example that uses your same Java config. Hopefully it will be of some use at debugging the issue: https://github.com/jzheaux/spring-security-examples/blob/master/stackoverflow-48998865

Comment: I opened this [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5071) on GitHub that mentions your example. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, that's great. I took a look at the issue, and it would be even more helpful if you had a sample project that reproduces your situation as the sample I sent you appears to work fine. Were you able to tweak it in such a way as to make it break in the way your application breaks?

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had the same issue. using thymeleaf.  Turned out that loginProcessingUrl is quite specific.

1. the form should have `method=POST`
2. the action on the form should be the same as what is used in the loginProcessingUrl

Otherwise it returns a 404.  Im guessing the endpoint is mapped with POST filter